# Typescript compile into UMD module not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, umd

I have a file named `a.ts` which looks like this:

```js
function abc(){
    alert("abc()")
}

export {abc}
```

And a second file named `b.ts` which looks like this:

```js
import * as a from "./a"

a.abc();
```

I compiled it with `tsconfig.json` of:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "umd",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": false,
        "outDir": "./outDir"
    },
    "files": [
        "b.ts",
        "a.ts"
    ],
}
```

And I get `a.js` like this:

```js
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    function abc() {
        alert("abc()");
    }
    exports.abc = abc;
});
```

And `b.js` looks like this:

```js
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object") {
        var v = factory(require, exports);
        if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;
    }
    else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define(["require", "exports", "./a"], factory);
    }
})(function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    var a = require("./a");
    alert("b.ts");
    a.abc();
});
```

And I write a simple test file `index.html`:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./b.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Nothing works. Doesn't `UMD` module supposed to working in browser??

Answer (score 1):

Based on the generated code I think it would not work until you add `requirejs` which supports `amd` module in the browser since above generated `umd` doesn't support browser object as described in a standard `umd` such as: https://github.com/umdjs/umd/blob/master/templates/commonjsStrict.js#L28

To sum up, it's likely to work if you add `https://requirejs.org/` with generated code above.

But in most use cases, in order to work best in the browser it's recommended to use `webpack` to combine things together